# C/Win32 : Minidumpwritedump give an empty file

Tags: c, winapi, minidumpwritedump

I want to dump the memory of a process with PID. Here is my code below :

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>

#include <DbgHelp.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

void EnableDebugPriv()
{
HANDLE hToken;
LUID luid;
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;

OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);

LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &luid);

tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tkp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, false, &tkp, sizeof(tkp), NULL, NULL);

CloseHandle(hToken); 
}

int main( int, char *[] )
{
EnableDebugPriv();
DWORD procid = 880;
HANDLE myfile = CreateFile(L"test.out", GENERIC_ALL, 0, 
NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
HANDLE processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procid);


printf("%d", processHandle);
if (processHandle = nullptr) {

    printf("error while getting handle");
}
MiniDumpWriteDump(processHandle, procid, myfile, MiniDumpWithFullMemory, 
NULL, NULL, NULL);

DWORD error = GetLastError();
printf("%d",error);

}
```

I use EnableDebugPriv() because I need admin rights to execute correctly my program.

Unfortunately the dump.out file is always empty, while the handle is not null, and I can't find why this issue happens ? (The process I want to dump is around 75mb with other tools like ProcDump).

Edit : Here is the error code given by GetLastError() : -2147024597

Comment: `if (processHandle = nullptr) {` should be `if (processHandle == nullptr) {`.

Comment: I make a mistake indeed, but it still doesn't work. I always got an empty file.

Comment: Check the result, and the error code if the result is FALSE.

Comment: The return is equal to 0 (FALSE I think obviously), so I edited my post with the error code.

Comment: Error code means `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY`. If you google it you'll see several discussions involving `MiniDumpWriteDump`.

Comment: After doing some tests, it appears that my code works perfectly on 32 bits process, but give an error code on 64 bit process. I think I must compile my program in x64 instead of x86 (I use Visual Studio Community), but now I got some errors related to dbghelp (unresolved external symbol). It's seems that I must link this file to my IDE.

Comment: My issue is finally resolved, thanks for help.

Comment: So, what was the problem?

Comment: The issue was that I tried (by stupid way) to dump a 64 bits process, but my program was build with x86 arch.